# Laravel Parse error on UsersController

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to list all users and so have created a UsersController which goes like:

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{

public function show(User $user)
{
    //
    $users = User::all();

    return view('superadmin.user.index', compact('users'));
}

}
```

And a Route that goes like:

```
Route::get('/superadmin/user', 'UsersController', function () {
        if(Auth::user()->role[0]->id != 3) {
            return redirect('/home');
        } else {
            return view('superadmin.user.index');
        }
});
```

and finally trying to call it with:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
  {{ $user->username }}
@endforeach
```

But I'm getting: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting ',' or ';'

On the class UsersController line, so i at least know its getting that far. Ive read all the parse error questions and followed a few tutorials on listing users but everything seems to hang up here.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You missing a `;` following your `namespace` or a `use ...` statement?

Comment: Yeah, something above `UsersController` has a syntax error. Also, your route declaration seems wrong. You're defining what happens on the route as closure, but still passing `UsersController` (without method too) for 2nd argument

Comment: create you route as in documentation and which version or php and laravel you are using ?

Comment: In your case I suggest you to use middleware instead of inline-check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A previous line to `class UsersController` did not end with semi colon.  It is a syntax error. Find the line and add semi colon `;`

Comment: until he share the lines above class. we cant say anything.

Comment: This was actually the case, although ali fixed the next issue that popped up. Thanks Harrison.

Comment: that's great Rath

Answer (score 1):

You have many issues:

In route you did not write to which method goes and it is not practical to return the view inside the route you can fix it as the following

```
Route::get('/superadmin/user/{user}', 'UsersController@show');
```

and in the controller make the operations you want.
If you want to check the rule of user you can make middleware and check the rules.

Comment: Thanks ali, this fixed the next issue i had.